# Clojure ring app on Elastic Beanstalk with Postgres Version errors

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, clojure, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a clojure ring app which I have previously pushed successfully to Elastic Beainstalk using lein-beanstalk. But now, since I've added PostgreSQL integration I've run into problems.

After deploying, what I get is a runtime exception: 
    `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.postgresql.Driver)`

From what I gather this is a version incompatibility and I'm guessing the Postgres drivers are built with Java 8 even though the documentation says that `"9.4-1201-jdbc41"` should work on Java 7 as well.

So I've tried a few different things, all of them resulting in the app no longer responding at all. First of all I created I new Elestic Beanstalk environment with Java 8, didn't work. Then I changed to the jdbc4 drivers instead of jdbc41, same result. I've tried adding `:javac-options ["-target" "1.8" "-source" "1.8"]` to the leinigen project and the same with 1.6. I also tried using `"9.4-1200-jdbc41"` drivers but I'm not even able to pull in the dependencies for that.

Anyone has any ideas on other things to try. The Java side of clojure deployment and AWS aren't really my forte so I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible.

For completeness, here is the dependency section of the .lein-file:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [liberator "0.12.2"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.3.2"]
                 [compojure "1.3.4"]
                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
                 [yesql "0.4.2"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4-1201-jdbc41"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.9.3"]
            [lein-beanstalk "0.2.7"]]
```

Comment: 9.4-1201-jdbc41 was compiled with the incorrect class file format (http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADK3HHKoMTghqWudO=r9=t-8n0s6uDwpGQDD=iM3o1c6MOZaLg@mail.gmail.com) . You could either try an earlier release, or you could use a snapshot build (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1203-SNAPSHOT/).

Comment: I tried both the 1202 snapshot, which still gave me the same run time exception, and the 1203 (from the link) which made the server stop responding entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was as Symfrog said, a miscompiled Postgres driver. The newer version fixed that. Only I had another problem lurking underneath, incorrect permission settings on AWS which was why the server then stopped responding. Everything is working now.